# php formulario select con campos de otra tabla sin estar conectadas

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `pk` int(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `residentes` varchar(50) COLLATE NOT NULL,
  `dniFamiliar` varchar(10) COLLATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `servicios` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci;

CREATE TABLE `servicios` (
  `codServicio` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `concepto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `precio` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1_spanish_ci;
```

tengo estas dos tablas, donde pedidos es para hacer facturas. todo con php

tengo que hacer un formulario en php con un select que me coja los campos de la tabla servicios para hacer la facturacion y guardarlo a la vez en una base de datos. me piden que lo haga con PDO orientado a objetos, pero no tengo ni idea de que es eso, pues acabo de hacer un curso del paro de 300 horas y ni lo he visto y en las practicas me piden esto, que ni me suena. solo vimos lo mas basico de lo basico
lo mas que he llegado a hacer es esto 
Concepto:

```
<select>
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    // Realizamos la consulta para extraer los datos
    $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM servicios");
    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        // En esta sección estamos llenando el select con datos extraidos de una base de datos.
        echo '<option value="'.$valores[codServicio].'">'.$valores[concepto].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

pero no me carga nada, no sale error, nada

Comment: Estas mezclando cosas, haces la query como objeto pero luego lo recorres como procedimiento.  Para PDO -> http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

Concepto: 
                                 
                                
                                        $resultado = $mysqli -> query ( "SELECT * FROM servicios" );
                                         if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
                                                $strHTML.='codServicio';
                                                $strHTML.='';
                                                    $strHTML.='Selección:';
                                            while ( $valores = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                                    $strHTML.='' . $valores[ 'codServicio' ] . '';
                                            }
                                                $strHTML.='';
                                            echo $strHTML;
                                        }else{
                                            $arrError=array("mensaje"=>"No se encontraron registros");
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        $arrError=array("mensaje"=>"La conexión a la base de datos no se puedo establecer. Revise conexion.php");
                                    }

ahora estoy en esto, y sigue sin salir nada

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta si deseas agregar lo que vas probando